# rug in Seaborn Histplot

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram

I have just started transitioning my Seaborn Histograms from `distplot` to `histplot`.

`rug=True` is always in my `distplots`, but it seems to be missing from `histplot`. Does anyone know what it should be replaced with to get the same outcome?

Comment: There is also [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot) which still has the `rug` parameter.

Comment: Yes, but that is a figure, not axis, level plot. As a result, you cannot add it to a subplot, which is what I needed in this case. However, overlaying an `sns.rugplot` works (even if its seems more cumbersome to me)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

For anyone else who is struggling with this:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(12, 8))

sns.histplot(data=data, x="x", kde=True, bins=10, ax=axs[0])
sns.rugplot(data=data, x="x", ax=axs[0])
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I have been struggling for some time to port my graph from `distplot`to 'histplot`.